# No converse of ratio test, so how to find ROC given convergence of coefficients?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

A student brought me this problem and I admit I am stumped:

Suppose we have the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ such that
$\lim_{n \to \infty}$ of the nth root of $|a_n|$ equals $L$ for $0 < L < \infty$

Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)a_{n+1} x^n$ be the series obtained by differentiating the original one term by term.  Show that the radius of convergence of the new series is $1/L$.

It looks plausible, but a proof eludes me.  The condition is the root test, and so we know that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ is absolutely convergent.  But that doesn't imply that $|a_{n+1}|/|a_n|$ goes to a limit less than $1$.

If $|x| \leq 1$,
I see how by a comparison test $a_n x^n$ would also converge.  But I don't see how to find the full radius of convergence.  It just seems like an odd problem that would require a converse of the ratio test that doesn't exist.

As another point, I read somewhere that the limit L in the root test is the same L as in the ratio test, but I don't see how to prove that and that would also be needed.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n=0} a_n $ is not absolutely convergent. It will converge if $0<L<1$.

The radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=0} a_n x^n$ is $1/L$ by the root test:
$$\sqrt[n]{|a_nx^n|} = \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\sqrt[n]{|x^n|}  = L|x| \Rightarrow |x|<1/L$$
The derivative will have the same radius of convergence
$$\sqrt[n]{|na_nx^n|} = \sqrt[n]{n}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\sqrt[n]{|x^n|}  = 1*L|x| \Rightarrow |x|<1/L$$